# Java 8 : Count the occurrence of digit 4 in the given int array

Tags: java-8, java-stream, streams-api

I am new to Java 8. I tried several ways to use the Streams API to solve the problem where we have been given an array of int = {48, 44, 4, 88, 84, 16, 12, 13 }. All I am trying to do is to find the occurrence of digit 4 in the whole array. I tried the following code -

```
int[] array = new int[] {48,44,4,88,84,16,12,13};

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for(int i:array) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        
        List<Integer> l = list.stream().filter(n->n%10)
                .map(n->n%10)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(l);
```

Please advice the Streams API way to solve this.

Comment: If you want to **count**  the occurrences of the digit 4 you need to return an `int` not a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: What is your actual result and your expected result? The way you couched the question, the result could be 5. But the way you've written the code, the result could be [48,44,4,84].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you need to obtain a **stream** from the given array of `int[]`. You can do it either by using the static method [`IntStream.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of(int...)), or with `Arrays` utility class and it's method [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)).

Both will give you an `IntStream` - a stream of `int` primitives. In order to collect stream elements into a *list* you need to convert it to a stream of *objects*. For that you can  apply method `boxed()` on the stream pipeline and each `int` element will get wrapped with `Integer` object.

In order to find all *elements* in the given *list* that contain a **target digit** (`4`), you can turn the **target digit** into a string and then apply a `filter` based on it.

```
public static List<Integer> findOccurrencesOfDigit(List<Integer> source, 
                                                   int digit) {
    String target = String.valueOf(digit);

    return source.stream()
                    .filter(n -> String.valueOf(n).contains(target))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {48,44,4,88,84,16,12,13};

    System.out.println(findOccurrencesOfDigit(nums, 4));
}
```

**Output**

```
[48, 44, 4, 84]
```

**Note:** method [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) expects a `Predicate` (a function represented by a boolean condition, that takes an element and return `true` of `false`)

Your attempt to create a predicate `filter(n -> n % 10)` is incorrect syntactically and logically. `n % 10` doesn't produce a boolean value, it'll give the right most digit of `n`.

If you want to use modulus (`%`) operator to create a predicate, you have to divide the element by `10` in a *loop* until it'll not become equal to `0`. And check before every division weather remainder is equal to the **target digit**. It could be done like that:

```
public static boolean containsDigit(int candidate, int digit) {
    boolean flag = false;
    while (candidate != 0) {
        if (candidate % 10 == digit) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        candidate /= 10; // same as candidate = candidate / 10;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

You can utilize this method inside a lambda expression like that (*note: it's a preferred way to avoid multiline lambda expressions by extracting them into separate methods*)

```
filter(n -> containsDigit(n, digit))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy way to do this is to convert the list of numbers to a string and count the ocurrences of the selected digit.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digit: " + i + " -> Ocurrences: " + countDigit(i, numbers);
  }
}

public static long countDigit(int target, List<Integer> numbers) {
  return numbers.stream().map(Object::toString) // Convert each number to string
                .collect(Collectors.joining()) // Join all of them into single string
                .chars() // Give me a stream of its characters
                .filter(c -> c == Character.forDigit(targer, 10)) // I just want the ones that are the same as my target
                .count(); // How many of them are there?
}
```

Comment: You can simplify that a lot with `flatMap()`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

- stream the array
- then in map, count the number of fours in each value using the remainder(%) operator.
- then return the count
- and sum those counts

```
int[] array = new int[] { 48, 44, 4, 88, 84, 16, 12, 13 };
        
int count = Arrays.stream(array).map(k-> {
    int sum = 0;
    while (k > 3) {
        sum += (k % 10 == 4) ? 1 : 0;
        k/=10;
    }
    return sum;
}).sum();

System.out.printf("There are %d fours.%n"m count);
```

prints

```
There are 5 fours.
```

If you're using Java 16+, you can use `mapMulti`

- simply put a 1 on the stream for every occurrence of 4.
- them sum them.

```
int count = Arrays.stream(array).mapMulti((i,consumer)->{
        while (i > 3) {
            if ((i%10) == 4) {
                consumer.accept(1);
            }
            i/=10;
        }}).sum();
```

And just for fun a third and less efficient way.

- convert the value to a String
- "remove" all characters except 4.
- return the length of remaining String.
- sum the lengths.

```
int count = Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(i -> Integer.valueOf(i).toString()
                        .replaceAll("[^4]", "").length())
            .sum();
```